# How to update fragement in background from sqlite when push notification comes?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, push-notification

I am using fragement and want to update the ui of listview in fragment from sqlite when push notification comes from the server.

Here is my broadcast reciever code in which i'm updating my fragment. With this code my fragment is updating but when i'll be on another activity and getting push notification that my app is crashing.

```
private void registerLocalBroadCastReciever() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("RefreshList"));

}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        /*
         * If employee onboard
         */
        String onBoardId = intent.getExtras().getString("ONBOARDING");
        if(!onBoardId.isEmpty()){               
            try {
                /*if(MapWindow.mMapWindowRunStatus){
                    MapWindow.mMapWindowRunStatus = false;
                    MapWindow.getInstace().finish();
                }*/

                DBHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).
                    updateCheckedBoardStatus("C", onBoardId, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }                           
        }

        TaskFragment tf = (TaskFragment) mTabPagerAdapter
                .getRegisteredFragment(TabsPagerAdapter.TASKFRAGMENT);
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (tf != null) {

            ft.detach(tf);
            ft.attach(tf);
            ft.commit();

            tf.loadTasks(false);
            tf.refreshTaskList();

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: First of all this is not a source code selling shop. show us what you have done so far